# UDP packet bytes read granularity?

Tags: networking, udp, boost-asio, asio

I have UDP client and server apps, and custom protocol over UDP.

Each "protocol packet"  contains header with size of payload, and payload by itself .

Each "protocol packet" not exceed MTU size, with expectation of lack of fragmentation .

Currently I'm using ASIO library and experiencing some problem:

Time diagram :

1. client send header (2 bytes) and payload (N < MTU-2 bytes) ------>
2. server reads only 2 bytes, to be sure about payload size.
3. server receive header with size of payload
4. server TRIED to receive N bytes of payload .....
   and nothing . Completion handler never occurs .

If client send (for debug purposes) one more packet, server completion handler is fired - what's why I think my async loop of asio is ok .

Also if server tried to read whole transmission  2+N bytes per one read ,
all data received .

So I'm little bit confused . It is possible to read separate bytes of one UDP datagram sequentially by executing _socket.async_receive_from() sequentally.

Will be glad for help,
Thanks in advance .

Comment: How does the server read these 2 bytes? And, what does the receive read handler say for bytes transferred? My guess is that this read gets all of the data, not just two bytes.

Comment: 2 bytes received correctly, "bytes transferred" contain exactly 2 bytes as requested by _socket.async_receive_from() . So I need someone who confirm my concerns , and it's look like where are some explanations already . Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to read separate bytes of one UDP datagram sequentially by executing _socket.async_receive_from() sequentally.

If this is a statement it is incorrect, and if it's a question the answer is 'no'. UDP is a datagram protocol.You get the entire datagram or nothing at all. If you read part of it the remainder is discarded.

Possibly you are looking for `readv()` or `recvmsg()`, which allow you to scatter-read.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. In my case "one datagram per time" is much better solution, than partial reading . Because each packet of protocol is self-sufficient and size of protocol < MTU, final code implementation will be not so complicated, in comparison of partial reading .
Anyway thanks for confirmation . Going to mark this answer as solution.